# export C# datatable data to excel using jumboexcel

Tags: c#, excel, datatable, jumboexcel

In my project I am getting data from the database and storing it in a datatable. From the datatable, I want to export the data to excel using jumboexcel. Please guide me how to achieve that.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please go through the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and the [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) sections to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to explore the [Demo Tests](https://github.com/george-polevoy/JumboExcel/tree/master/JumboExcel.DemoTests) namespace in the [JumboExcel](https://github.com/george-polevoy/JumboExcel) github project.

JumboExcel builds on a concept of LINQ, so if you are working with an IEnumerable, Entity Framework, Dapper, or any kind of database client which exposes data sets as IEnumerable, getting it to work with JumboExcel is straightforward:

```
var worksheets = new[] {
    new WorksheetElement("Persons", new WorksheetParametersElement(false,false),
    (from p in db.Persons
    order p by p.Name
    select new Row(
            new InlineString(i.Name),
            new InlineString(i.Age)
        )
    ).Take(100000));

// var fileName = @".....\My File.xlsx";
using (var outputStream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.CreateNew))
{
    OpenXmlBuilder.Write(
        outputStream,
        worksheets
    );
}
```

Comment: See the link below: http://csharp.net-informations.com/excel/csharp-excel-oledb.htm
That should do what you want.